# UIActionSheet deprecated: how to replace it when it contains custom controls?

Tags: ios, uiactionsheet

`UIActionSheet` has been deprecated in iOS 8.3. The suggestion is to replace it with `UIAlertController`, however, my `UIActionSheet` is set up to contain an `UISegmentedControl` and an `UIDatePicker`. `UIAlertController` documentation explicitly says:

> Important
>
> The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not
>   support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and
>   must not be modified.

So clearly I cannot use `UIAlertController`. What is my best option?

Comment: `UIActionSheet` never actually supported adding custom controls even if you got it to work. `UIAlertController` is no different. Your best option is to right (or find) a custom popup that does what you want.

Comment: You have many options, actually. Keep using `UIActionSheet`, customize `UIAlertController` or stop be a rebel and create a custom View Controller.

Comment: I'm afraid you are right. Adding subviews to `UIActionSheet` was easy and convenient, and never explicitly forbidden AFAICR.

Comment: @Jean-DenisMuys From the documentation for `UIActionSheet`: *"UIActionSheet is not designed to be subclassed, nor should you add views to its hierarchy. If you need to present a sheet with more customization than provided by the UIActionSheet API, you can create your own and present it modally with present(_:animated:completion:)"*. `UIAlertController` documentation states something similar.

Comment: @maddy I stand corrected. Thank you